# How to invoke python/flask server to reload client page from server-side function?

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a small python/flask project, which interfaces a heavy computation routine with a browser interface. For practical reasons, I have to keep the computation in a background process and reload/redirect the page (with output results) when the computation is done. The following is a minimal code of what I have so far (in reverse order):

`interface.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

# step 4: rerender browser with output data
@app.route('/done')
def done(data_to_pass):
    # rerender browser's html here?
    print data_to_pass
    return data_to_pass

# step 3: heavy computation routine
def background():
    print "start runing backgroun process"
    time.sleep(3) # simulate heavy computation routine
    data = 'done from background'
    done(data)

# step 2: initiate background process
def init():
    t = Thread(target=background)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

# step 1: home interface
@app.route('/')
def front_end():
    init()
    return 'initiate bachground process'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When the `interface.py` is running, accessing 127.0.0.1:5000 get a string `initiate bachground process` in the browser. However, the final data (string `done from background` in this case) only been processed in the server's terminal, not to the browser.

I believe this procedure is commonly done for most of the server, but I can't find any flask solution... Or do I go in the wrong direction?

Comment: What happens when you hit your `/done` route?

Comment: Do you mean accessing 127.0.0.1:5000/done directly from the browser? Under this setup, `done` expect an input argument from function call. So directly access it from the address 127.0.0.1:5000/done gives internal server error.

Comment: Are you intending to poll using the `/done` route? So you would first request `/` and then call `/done` at intervals until it returns something?

Comment: What I have in mind is to request `/` first, which calls `/done` from the server side when the computation is done. I have no idea how this should be done and I though it can be achieved purely from the flask side (without messing with javascript or whatsoever)... But maybe I must go with suggestions from @barjey

Comment: If you don't want to poll then that's the way to go. You could also look at server sent events, which are simpler than websockets and comet (long polling). There is a flask example snippet [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/) which may provide a few pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when the process is finished I would suggest to use one of:

- Long polling
- WebSocket

However you can reload whole page:

```
window.location.reload()
```

it is a good practice to return from the server only the result of the background process and update only related fragment of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! [This](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) seems like what I need. But I thought this can be done in a much simpler way...?

Comment: Nope, you cannot send data to browser from server unless you have an open connection.